# PHP Error Checking Issue

Tags: php

Set some guidelines for users to follow as far as input goes and I believe my syntax and coding is right but maybe I'm not referencing my second php file correctly? I'm new to php so my first instinct is to use an onfocus or onblur function for my text boxes but that would be wrong so any help would be really useful. Thanks.

index.php

```
    <span class ="error"> * required field </span>
  <form name ="myForm" action ="display.php<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>"   
        method = "POST"><br>

  Name: <input type="text" name="userName" value ="<?php echo $name;?>" 
               <span class ="error"> *<?php echo $nameErr;?></span><br>
  University: <input type="text" name="userUniv" value ="<?php echo $university;?>"
               <span class ="error"> *<?php echo $univErr;?></span><br> 
  Email: <input type ="text" name ="userEmail" value ="<?php echo $email;?>"
               <span class ="error"> *<?php echo $emailErr;?></span><br><br>
```

display.php

```
<?php
$nameErr = $emailErr = $univErr = "";
$name = $email = $university = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["userName"])) {
        $nameErr = "Name is required";
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["userName"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {
            $nameErr = "Invalid name"; 
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["userEmail"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["userEmail"]);
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["userUniv"])) {
        $univErr = "University is required";
    } else {
        $university = test_input($_POST["userUniv"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $university)) {
            $univErr = "Invalid University"; 
        }
    }
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: What is this `action ="display.php<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>"`? Shouldn't it be `second.php`?

Comment: sorry my actual file name is display.php

Comment: Are you wanting your error variables from display.php to show up in the form on index.php? There is no indication in your display.php what you are doing with those error messages. If that is so you need the code from display.php inside of index.php and checking with post or if the form has been submitted.

Comment: I want those messages to be displayed on the * mark, that's why I tried implementing the php at that point. I was thinking of that too but didn't think I could utilize an onlick function with the submit button with php

Answer (score 0):

When your form action is `display.php` you're redirecting away from the form so it has no reference to the layout anymore, there are a few ways that you could go about displaying the data. Having the action as the current page and do all logic within or save the error messages into a session and redirect the page back to the form and display or validate via ajax.

I'll demonstrate the former. Also you'll want to remove the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, this will make your action something like `display.php/display.php` assuming it's in the root.

```
<?php
    $nameErr = $emailErr = $univErr = "";
    $name = $email = $university = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["userName"])) {
            $nameErr = "Name is required";
        } else {
            $name = test_input($_POST["userName"]);
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {
                $nameErr = "Invalid name"; 
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["userEmail"])) {
            $emailErr = "Email is required";
        } else {
            $email = test_input($_POST["userEmail"]);
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
            }
        }
        if (empty($_POST["userUniv"])) {
            $univErr = "University is required";
        } else {
            $university = test_input($_POST["userUniv"]);
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $university)) {
                $univErr = "Invalid University"; 
            }
        }
    }

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
?>


<span class ="error"> * required field </span>
<form name="myForm" action="" method = "POST">
    <br>
    Name: <input type="text" name="userName" value ="<?php echo $name;?>" 
           <span class ="error"> *<?php echo $nameErr;?></span><br>
    University: <input type="text" name="userUniv" value ="<?php echo $university;?>"
           <span class ="error"> *<?php echo $univErr;?></span><br> 
    Email: <input type ="text" name ="userEmail" value ="<?php echo $email;?>"
           <span class ="error"> *<?php echo $emailErr;?></span><br><br>
           <input type="submit" value="submit me">
</form>
```